# WebDav as MediaServer

Tags: windows, linux, networking, streaming, webdav

I am wondering if makes sense, to use `WebDav` as a media server, to stream Movies (in the best case), but at least stream my Music.

I have a 100MBit Internet connection with about 5MBit Upload, so in theory, I should be able to listen to my Music from wherever I am.

I tried different MediaServers but wasn't happy with them at all.

What do you think, will this be a good idea? Especially, what will happen, if I try to stream big files (100MB or maybe 10GB or more)?

Comment: I think for streaming purposes, you only need HTTP, WebDAV extensions are for write access over HTTP.

Comment: @KovBal Thank you for your answer, but I want to use my media library as a network drive. So that I am able to manage it. Do you think it will work nice with HTTP?

Comment: What media server products did you try? Most of them are going to either provide access via HTTP or UPnP.

Comment: @slm Well I tried Ampache and NetJukeBox, but Ampache didn't worked because, it doesn't support Php 5.4 and NetJukeBox is a bit buggy. Also I thought UPnP was only available to local Networks? Do you recommend me any UPnP servers? It should run on a low end Linux server (700MHz dualcore 128 mb Ram)

Answer (score 1):

I have no practical experience with this application but it purports to take LAN UPnP devices and expose them out over the internet. It's called [BubbleUPnP Server](http://www.bubblesoftapps.com/bubbleupnpserver/) and it sounds like it might be what you're looking for.

> BubbleUPnP Server provides new services on top of your existing
>   UPnP/DLNA devices: secure Internet access to your UPnP/DLNA Media
>   Servers content with BubbleUPnP for Android and foobar2000 on Windows.
>   stream and download your music, video, photos with your Android device
>   from a mobile or WiFi connection with optional transcoding to reduce
>   bandwidth. no need to sync, to upload to the cloud, to register to an
>   online service, ... You're in control! create OpenHome Media Renderers
>   from any UPnP AV renderer (provides on-device playlist, multiple
>   Control Point access to the same renderer). Works with BubbleUPnP for
>   Android. fix issues of UPnP/DLNA Media Servers (discovery issues,
>   broken data, add some audio DLNA compliance) by creating a proxy Media
>   Server BUBBLEUPNP SERVER IS NOT AN UPNP AV MEDIA SERVER It requires at
>   least one working UPnP AV Media Server (Windows Media Player, Twonky,
>   Asset UPnP, ...) or Media Renderer to do something useful.

Check out the [What is BubbleUPnP Server?](http://www.bubblesoftapps.com/bubbleupnpserver/#what_is_bubble_upnp_server) page for more information about it's capabilities.